# What is the format in which PHP sends queries to SQL Server and How to check if the SQL query in PHP and SQL Server is same?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

What is the format in which PHP sends queries to SQL Server? Is that some human readable code?
How to check if the SQL query in PHP and SQL Server is same?
How can I tell the SQL Server to not to accept any injection?

Please share any link or knowledge you know in this regard.

Comment: Your question to broad not to mentioned that you should not put your question as title. Additionally, put some effort by posting what you have got so far.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: SQL injection is trivial to avoid: parametrised queries. If you don't do that, then it's just impossible to say if a given piece of SQL code was composed intentionally or not: that's why it's a problem in the first place.

Comment: After recent meeting with some client, these questions are bothering me. I want to increase and share knowledge in this regard.

Comment: This is essentially [a duplicate of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975897/is-injection-possible-in-between-php-and-sql-server).

Comment: @halfer - Yes, it is. And I think he's confusing SQL injection with man in the middle attacks or traffic sniffing. Everything that's sent unencrypted through a network is visible in that network.

Comment: @Álvaro, agreed. OP, to summarise: it is theoretically possibly to modify database server traffic if you can get access to the private network it runs on. This is extremely hard to do, and is not something to worry about (unless you are poking the NSA with a sharp stick). We would not in general call this "SQL injection", although the results might be similar - it is a different kind of attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL injection is a simple as widely misunderstood.

SQL (as most other computer languages) is text where you have:

- Language specific keywords: `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `FROM`...
- Custom identifiers: customers, providers, shipping_history...
- Data: Hamlet, Patrick O'Brian, 3.1416, 21st August 1974...

The language provides a syntax to tell them apart (in SQL, it basically depends on context, quotes and what character it starts with).

SQL is safe because a random user is not allowed to access the database server and run arbitrary queries. For example, the database is password protected. Thus a hacker can't just connect and do:

```
SELECT credit_card FROM customers;
DELETE FROM criminal_records;
```

SQL injection happens when you allow a random user to generate SQL code and you gladly run the resulting code for him:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='' or '1'='1'
```

Now you have some perfectly valid SQL code. That code is only text so there's no way to say where each individual character came from. Text does not have memory.

As I said, it's trivial to avoid:

- Query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE password=?`
- Data: `' or '1'='1`

Now we don't even need to care about injection: that's the exact SQL code written by **us**, not some other guy.